# Apache HTTPD: How to setup Virtual Host correctly

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I've installed **Apache httpd** on my Mac and "It works".

Now I need to configure a **Virtual Host** in order to expose my application (Java Spring) with httpd as reverse proxy in front of it.

This is what I have into **/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf** file

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName my.domain.it:443
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/cert.key
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/myapp
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/myapp
</VirtualHost>
```

In `/etc/hosts` I've mapped to server address in this way:

```
127.0.0.1       my.domain.it
```

And The Tomcat Connector configuration is:

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" proxyPort="443" scheme="https"/>
```

If I run the application with Eclipse it responds correctly at http://localhost:8080/myapp/ but If I try to call https://my.domain.it/myapp/ It doesn't work and Google Chrome tells me: "This site can't be reached".

What's wrong with my configuration?

P.S.
The httpd Apache instance is configured to Listen on port 80

```
#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
```

Thanks.

EDIT: SOLVED
Unfortunately I was not able to solve with Apache Httpd but now with Nginx it works. Thanks for your answers

Comment: Check with netstat if the server is listening at 127.0.0.1:443 in the first place. If not check if the server is even started. Also check the error logs of the server.

Answer (score 0):

In mod_ssl.conf (file name might be different) you should have the following line

```
Listen 443
```

It tells apache to listen on port 443 (it's include in the configuration file when you install mod_ssl to be able to expose your site over HTTPS).
The same configuration file should include all the shared configuration about the TLS.

If apache is running, you can check if port 443 is listening, using netstat:

```
netstat -an | grep -i list
```

The output should include port 80 and 443 (and some other according to the services running on the server such as ssh).

If the port is shown in the list, next step is to check apache logs for errors.