# Google Chrome: how to bypass SSL check for develop purpose

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, vhosts

I need to test a web application on localhost with a custom domain name es: my.domain.com using the HTTPS protocol (I'm using self signed certs).

I've setup a vhost in my `httpd.conf` and added an entry to my `/etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1 my.domain.com
```

But Google Chrome block with an ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR "this site can't provide a secure connection".

I tried to disable the security checks into the Chrome settings but nothing changed still got the ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR problem.

Is it possibile to bypass this thing for develop purpose only?

Important: I can't change my domain name because of settings in order to make a Single Sign On works

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a different TLD, especially .internal ?

Comment: @Marged unfortunately I can't because of domain settings in order to make a Single Sign On works

Comment: That's an important restriction that you should mention in your question

Comment: *"ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"* - looks like a setup problem of the server on localhost or on the URL you use (like trying to access a HTTP-only server with `https://`). Only, there is __nothing__ known about this setup nor on the link you use.

Comment: Hi @SteffenUllrich I've posted another Issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65687903/apache-httpd-how-to-setup-virtual-host-correctly In this topic I'm trying to explain the problem I had the day before when my local site was unreachable but today Chrome show me a different message.